# Set SERVER_URL for several environments

Tags: grails, vue.js, environment-variables

I have a Grails/VueJS project and I am wondering how i can define different SERVER_URL for each environment.

I deploy on AWS on 4 different environments (with different urls), and I need this SERVER_URL to be well configured to call my controllers.

Today I have my config files :

[image]

But I can only have one value in prod.env.js

By default, the production mode is used in build.js:

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

But how can I specify different urls for my 4 environments, and use the right SERVER_URL ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `SERVER_URL` variable to each config with value you need, example **prod.env.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    NODE_ENV: '"production"',
    SERVER_URL: '"https://server.com/"',
    CLIENT_ID: '"some client stuff"',
    CLIENT_URL: '"some another client stuff"'
}
```

And in source code just use `process.env.SERVER_URL` and it will be replaced with `"https://server.com/"` by *webpack DefinePlugin* during bundling.

So to build for production you need run something like this **with correct** `NODE_ENV` value (just add this to package.json scripts section to not type it everytime):

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node build/build.js
```

P.S. `cross-env` is utility to set environment variable across different platforms, **it should be installed via npm**.